# What does it mean (Class *)?

Tags: objective-c, syntax

Example:

```
- (Subclass *)field:(NSArray *)fields
{
    // code      
    return (Subclass *)[self field:fields];
}
```

I've seen more than once where it is used `(Class *)`. So, what does it mean?

Comment: You mean with a class name, or literally `(Class *)` ?

Comment: an endless-loop as example ^^ class is calling itself as return-value :D and " * " is always the pointer (adress) to an object, an important thing in object oriented programming and memory handling.

Comment: literally, where can I use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example says that the method returns pointer to an instance of class Subclass.
The second one is casting, it's just telling the compiler that  [self field:fields] is Subclass type (pointer an instance of class Subclass).